# Elemento en lista sin repetirse

Tags: python-3.x

En nuevo nombre (la variable) debe salir un elemento de la lista de nuevos nombres y no se debe repetir. Por cada elemento añadido a la primera lista se debe sustituir por otro de la otra lista.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from random import randrange                                                                                
listaDeNombres = [] # Esta lista debe comenzar vacía 
                                                 
listaDeNuevosNombres = ["Ládelbar", "Éldelgym", "Álcampo", "Legóteas", "Élgolon", "Ládelgas", "Eldélcole"]
# vvvv Escribe aquí el código para introducir nombres a la lista "listaDeNombres" vvvv
listaDeNombres.append("Elperfecto")
listaDeNombres.append("Laexperta")
listaDeNombres.append("Yoigo")
listaDeNombres.append("Vendepan")
listaDeNombres.append("Fueralejos")
listaDeNombres.append("Lifestyle")
listaDeNombres.append("Breakthrough")
listaDeNombres.append("Baffled")    

# ^^^^ Escribe aquí el código para introducir nombres a la lista "listaDeNombres" ^^^^

for nombre in listaDeNombres:
    
    # vvvv Escribe aquí tu código vvvv
    # No debe haber nuevos nombres repetidos
    tamlistaDeNuevosNombres = len(listaDeNuevosNombres)
    indiceNuevoNombre = randrange(0, tamlistaDeNuevosNombres)
   
        
    print (f"El nombre de {nombre} será ahora {nuevoNombre}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Sólo hay que agregar unas líneas en el `for`:

```
for nombre in listaDeNombres:
    tamlistaDeNuevosNombres = len(listaDeNuevosNombres)
    if tamlistaDeNuevosNombres < 1:
        break
    indiceNuevoNombre = randrange(0, tamlistaDeNuevosNombres)

    nuevoNombre = listaDeNuevosNombres[indiceNuevoNombre]
    del listaDeNuevosNombres[indiceNuevoNombre]

    print(f"El nombre de {nombre} será ahora {nuevoNombre}")
```

El ciclo recorre los nombres actuales. En cada pasada selecciona al azar un nombre de la lista nueva

```
    tamlistaDeNuevosNombres = len(listaDeNuevosNombres)
    if tamlistaDeNuevosNombres < 1:
        break
    indiceNuevoNombre = randrange(0, tamlistaDeNuevosNombres)

    nuevoNombre = listaDeNuevosNombres[indiceNuevoNombre]
```

Agregamos un `break` en caso que no haya suficientes nombres nuevos.

Para evitar repeticiones, el nombre seleccionado es eliminado de la lista:

```
    del listaDeNuevosNombres[indiceNuevoNombre]
```

Produce:

```
El nombre de Elperfecto será ahora Ládelbar
El nombre de Laexperta será ahora Eldélcole
El nombre de Yoigo será ahora Álcampo
El nombre de Vendepan será ahora Éldelgym
El nombre de Fueralejos será ahora Ládelgas
El nombre de Lifestyle será ahora Legóteas
El nombre de Breakthrough será ahora Élgolon
```